# Symfony2 - add flashbag message on entity operations

Tags: symfony, notifications, crud

I'm working on a Symfony2.3.6 project, and it works good. I've made a backend side with a few CRUD for some Entities, and it also work good.

Now what I want to do is notify an user when an operation is made on an entity. So I want to notify when an entity is saved, updated or deleted, as Symfony1.4 made. 
I was in doubt where to put the flashbag message, if in the entity or in the controller or even with events?!

Which is the right place where I can put this kind of feature, and how I can do it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) describes perfectly how to store and display these messages in your controller.

## In your controller

```php
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(...);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do some sort of processing

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Your changes were saved!'
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(...));
    }

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

## In your Twig template

```twig
% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can use different flashbags for other messages, for example an error :

## In your controller

```php
[...]
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'delete',
            'The entity has been deleted!'
        );
[...]
```

## In your Twig template

```twig
% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('delete') %}
    <div class="flash-notice delete">
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Use CSS to style the `delete` class.

Comment: Ok ok, in fact I had already made this way. But, if I have, let's suppose, 5 entities, do I have to write down all this code for each entity? Isn't better use events? ...in my tests I was not able to work with events, that's way I've used this approach...

Comment: I don't know about events, I use the solution as presented in my answer. There is a bit of code duplication because the same code is in every function of the controller, but it's easy to use and adapt to different entities ans messages.